# Put parameters in docker container of Angular app

Tags: angular, docker, environment-variables, dockerhub

I have an angular application and it was required to me to put it in a docker image. My first version of the Dockerfile is as next:

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###

# We label our stage as 'builder'
FROM node:8-alpine as builder

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY . .

## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer


### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine

## Copy our default nginx config
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## From 'builder' stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Now, as the project have the environment files I need to find a way that I can pass those parameters like "enviroment" variables of the docker containers, example `docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE myImage`

So, I infer that I will need to set those values inside the environment file before make the compilation, but I don't know how to achieve it.
I would like to get some help on this matter, and thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). You can define your environment variables inside a `docker-compose.yml` file. If using the `env_file` configuration option, you could also declare multiple variables in a separate file.

From the documentation:

> **Set environment variables in containers**
>
> You can set environment
>   variables in a service’s containers with the ‘environment’ key, just
>   like with docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE ...:
>
> web:
>     environment:
>       - DEBUG=1
>
> **Pass environment variables to containers**
>
> You can pass environment variables from your shell straight through to a service’s containers
>   with the ‘environment’ key by not giving them a value, just like with
>   docker run -e VARIABLE ...:
>
> web:
>     environment:
>       - DEBUG

Here is a small example setting a environment variable `DEBUG` to `development` inside a container:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

version: "3"
  services:
    example:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      environment:
        - DEBUG="development"
```

Setup:

```
# build 
./docker-compose build
# start
./docker-compose up
# display all declared variables in container
./docker-compose exec example env
```

Since you would like to use an image from dockerhub you could simply pull the image using docker-compose:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  example:
    image: ubuntu
  environment:
    - DEBUG="development"
  entrypoint:
    - <YOURENTRYPOINT>
```

Pull the specified service image:

```
./docker-compose pull example
```

Run the container:

```
./docker-compose up example
```

**Reference**

- [`Environment variables in Compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: nice approach! however my clients needs and want the images build in docker-hub, so, I must generrate the images and catch te values from the docker run command

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova - But shouldn't you be able to use a `docker-compose.yml` file and pull the desired Dockerfile from dockerhub?

Comment: I am not following you, don't understand

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova - You should be able to specify an image to use in your docker-compose.yml file. I updated my answer. Not really sure I understand what you're trying to do here =)

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595829/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-a-frontend-web-application/49349963#49349963