# Angular Docker Runtime Environments

Tags: angular, typescript, docker

I have an **angular** app, which runs with nginx in a docker container. The docker image is publish in a private docker hub. Now I want to pass the environments from docker to **compiled** angular application. At time I create a `config.json` and a `ConfigService`, which reads out the file. The file can be change over docker volume. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to use the environment variable in the module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment.system.googleMaps.apiKey // old way
    }),
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    ConfigService
    ...
  ]
})
export class ContractsModule {}
```

Besides, it is only a workaround. Perfect would be to use the docker environment. Have some an idea?

I think this is a good way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49349963/8581092.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass environment variables to a frontend web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595829/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-a-frontend-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the ENV keyword when building the docker image or --env when running the image.

[docker run command with env](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)

Comment: The question I ask myself is rather, how do I pass the variables in the compiles Angular application.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to create a properties file which you can refer using `--env-file` flag while executing `docker run` command as shown below:

```
docker run -d --env-file ENV_FILE_NAME IMAGE_NAME
```

The properties file make it easy to add or remove the env variables in the docker image.

Please ensure that the file is in the same directory where you are executing the `docker run` command.

Comment: Good idea. So I can change properties after docker image build, right? Unfortunately I'm looking for a better solution than my current one for passing the properties to compiled angular application. The best would be, I guess, if I provide the properties via Javascript before Angular is loaded.

Comment: @William As I mentioned in the answer you specify the file while executing `docker run`. So yes you can change properties after the docker image build.