# How to use environment variables change at runtime with Docker without breaking Angular PWA

Tags: angular, docker, environment-variables, progressive-web-apps

I have a web application written in Angular, containerized in Docker. I previously solved the problem of runtime environment variables (for dev/prod environment) with these nice solutions:
[How to pass environment variables to a frontend web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595829/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-a-frontend-web-application)

But ! When you write an Angular PWA, any post-build change into the files, even `index.html`, will break your PWA: the service worker will fail to validate your files since the hash has changed compared to `ngsw.json`.

I cannot think of a good way to keep the "build once, deploy everywhere" pattern with Angular PWA and Docker.

Any idea ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, how did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi. No I didn't find a good solution for now, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

My main*.js file was having this issue in ngsw.json after the container modified env vars at runtime. The solution I came up with is to remove the problematic file(s) from Angular's ngsw-config.json and do not rely on it.

Next, create a separate sw script (mine is sw-handle-main.js) and in a sw-master script file, call importScripts on that sw-handle-main and also calls importScripts on the ngsw-worker.js created by Angular. Be sure you are registering this master js file in the ServiceWorkerModule.register call and importing your custom file FIRST like:

sw-master.js

```
importScripts('./sw-handle-main.js');
importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js');
```

In your app.component.ts, you need to create a method that calls getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT') and check each src attr. If the src url contains "main" (in my case),  push that src url onto an array. Then call the postMessage method to pass this data to the sw-handle-main. In sw-handle-main.js, listen for the "message" event, and pass the urls to a cache.add() call. You also need to add an event listener on the fetch event and call event.respondWith(). DO NOT wait to call event.respondWith() inside any promise, or else the ngsw-worker will gobble it up and your file will never register the fetch listener for it. Call it synchronously by passing some synchronous conditional. Mine sw-handle-main is like:

```
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
event.waitUntil(initCacheAction(event.data.urls))
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const req = event.request
  const url = req.url
  if(url.indexOf('main') > -1 && url.endsWith('.js')){
   event.respondWith(matchJSFile(req))
  }
});
```

matchJSFile(req) is a Promise. It is ok to pass one to respondWith(). Just don't wait to invoke respondWith inside an async method as I said before.

**Another tip is to basically steal the appVersion from the Angular SW like below:

```
function getAppVersion() {
const cachePrefix = 'ngsw:/:'
const cacheSuffix = 'app:cache'
return caches.keys().then( cacheKeys => {
  //get any ngsw caches that holds appShell
  const appCache = cacheKeys.filter( item => {
    return item.indexOf(cacheSuffix) > -1
  })
  const len = appCache.length
  //use the last 1 inserted
  const appCacheName = appCache[len - 1]
  if(appCacheName){
    //lets us know sw app version
    return appCacheName.
    replace(cachePrefix, '').
    replace(cacheSuffix, '')
  }
  return null
})
```

}

cachePrefix and cacheSuffix are the fixed names that Angular gives the cache object containing you app shell. The long random string in between them is your appVersion. You can also verify in the /ngsw/state. With this, you can use this key in your custom cache object and maintain your custom cache's integrity/recency, and delete old caches you made that do not match the key! If you want more of my utility code for all this, just let me know but this is working for me! I really hope I explained this well enough for you to get yours working!